# Advanced Multivariable Analysis Textbooks

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for difficult problems on multivariable analysis: roughly the material covered in Spivak's *Caculus on Manifolds*, but with harder (and more) problems. What are some good textbook or problem books?

Some other books I've looked at (so please don't include these in your answer): Baby Rudin, Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*. The problem with these is that problems are mostly basic (Rudin) or too few in number (Munkres).

Comment: Grab Cartan's Differential Calculus or chapter 8 of Dieudonne's Foundations of Modern analysis. Both books can be thought as a long exercise in which the authors provided only hints as to how show them.